# Adding array even values through For-loop. C#

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, for-loop

I am to establish an array and add only the even numbers in the array through a `for-loop`. I've established the array but unsure how to apply it in the loop. I think I have to use the `%` operator to only select the even numbers in the array. I know how to set up a typical For-Loop but unclear how to use it with an array. Any help works.

```
int[] bills = new int[5];

bills[0] = 131;
bills[1] = 121;
bills[2] = 2000;
bills[3] = 333;
bills[4] = 120;
bills[5] = 334;
```

Comment: Why don't you attempt to set up a for loop in your question so that any answer doesn't have to start from scratch?

Comment: by the way, the `bills[5]` will cause index out of bounce exception

Comment: try this : for(int i = 0; i < bills.Count; i += 2).  Do you want the even numbers or the even index numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick suggestion, use `%` (modulus) operator check for remainder like `arrayvalue % 2 == 0` if condition `true` then it's even number else odd.

```
foreach(int val in bills)
{
    if(val % 2 == 0)
    {
        //It's even number ... do your processing
    }
    else { continue; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feed back! This helped!

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner, you could start using `foreach` loop to loop through each value. To see the value is even or odd just apply modulus operator and check reminder is zero or not.

```
foreach(int bill in bills)
{
    if(bill%2 ==0)
    {
        //logic here
    }
}
```

Another approach, using `Linq`.

```
int[] onlyEventValues = bills.Where(x=> x%2==0).ToArray(); // filters and returns an array of even values.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach` to loop all numbers you have
Use `List<int>` to save only even numbers

```
List<int> evenNumbers = new List<int>();
foreach(int val in bills)
{
    if(val % 2 == 0)
    {
        evenNumbers.Add(val);
    }
}
```